# Unrendered Pixels (Holes) in Blender Internal Render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Here is my problem and I have never seen this before in Blender:

I'm making a Minecraft Animation and on multiple frames there are unrendered transparent pixels scattered across the image (resulting in black spots). I have googled around and only found answers related to Cycles render which doesn't apply to my situation as I use Blender Internal.

I made a video explanation to show in detail what is happening:

[[image: Example problematic rendered Frame]

(https://youtu.be/YbWy8n2figo)](https://youtu.be/YbWy8n2figo)

UPDATE: Thank's all those who helped me out. It turned out to be a problem with "Auto Ray Bias." This thread answered my problem.
[Cause of Alpha or Black Artefacts in Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34074/cause-of-alpha-or-black-artefacts-in-render)

Comment: Hello new user, and welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. If you *pack* and [post your .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) it will be 10 times more helpful for diagnosing your problem.

Comment: Check whether this isn't [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), make sure to unhide all the objects in scene and see if there are any surprises, also check whether there's repeating geometry inside of one mesh. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render

Comment: Good call @MrZak it is Z-Fighting, If you post this as an answer, I have an animated GIF to prove it on this blend you can steal to put in your answer if you'd like - [The Link to the GIF](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zX2uD.gif).

Comment: RELATED: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38752/is-there-any-way-to-stop-z-fighting-besides-remove-doubles AND: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces/40698#40698