# Rendering Multiple Frames Makes my Animation Grainy

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

Sorry if this question has already been asked but I'm kinda desperate at this point. I have recently started using Blender for animations. Whenever I see people post animations they made in Blender online they always look crystal clear and the colors really pop. But for some reason whenever I try to render out multiple frames to later put together in the video sequence editor my images look grainy and not as  bright once they are placed in the finished and placed in the folder. But when I'm sitting there watching the images render on my laptop they look pretty clear and all the colors pop. It only seems to happen when I render multiple images at once, I have tried turning up my samples, resolution and other settings but no matter how cranked my they are or how long the render seems to take it still doesn't look as clear as it could be. Here are some example pictures of what is going on and what my settings look like.

[image]

This is what it looks like while it's is rendering

[image]

This is what it looks like once it's placed in a folder when it's finished rendering.

[image]

And these are my settings.

Sorry again for the long explanation and any help or advice would be much appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

Here is a picture of color management settings as well

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE! Share a .blend (or part of it) via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com if you can. It'll be easier to investigate.

Comment: I notice you’re rendering out to JPEG which is inherently lossy. Try changing to PNG.

Comment: I added the .blend file. I have also tried rendering the images as PNG files and I still have the same problem, thanks though!

Comment: Hm, I don't see any difference for my render tests. Try latest Blender build https://builder.blender.org/download/

Comment: I tried rendering it again in the latest blender and I am still experiencing the same issue. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49843/dirty-specks-in-cycles-animation/49844#49844